# How to have few options as checked in the entity/choice type in symfony

Tags: symfony

I want to render the choice type from entity and its working fine. I want to few options to be checked by default when the form is rendered. For e.g. I have 10 options out of it only 3 options to be checked by default and when it persisted and in edit page whatever is saved to database should be rendered not the default 3 items. In the below title is fieldname

```
->add('attendee', EntityType::class, [
    'label' => 'Select any information you would like to
    require per Attendee:',
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
    'required' => true,
    'class' => 'AppBundle\\Entity\\Registrant',
    'choice_label' => 'title',
  ])
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have saved some values, then symfony will select the values in the form itself. You don't need to preselect them. You need in your form type the method "configureOptions" like this:

```
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\MyClass'
    ));
}
```

If it is not working anyway, post more code.

Comment: Did you joined the registrant entity with the attendee entity with doctrine many2many or something like this?